# Responsive menu - parent menu with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I may possible have a requirement where i have to link the parent menu to a link rather than showing sub menu. Right now i am using Slick Menu `http://slicknav.com/`

Logically parent menu should not be linked as it should show child menu on mobile device. while desktop version we can counter this with hover effect can show sub-menus and click on the parent menu can open link also but on small screen we can either open link or show submenu.

my question right now is that in fiddle example (http://jsfiddle.net/y1dLdd1f/1/) i am linking `Parent 1` meny to `google.com`, but script is blocking this. How can i unblock it and when user click on it it opens the page rather than showing the sub menu if parent menu has a proper link

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Parent 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
            <li>Parent 3
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">item 8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item 10</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li>non-link item</li>
    <li>Parent 2
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slick menu has a number of available options including "allowParentLinks", all you need should be,...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu').slicknav({
        allowParentLinks:"true"
    });
});
```

But to show this working in JSFiddle you would need to add target="_blank" to you <a> tag.